# sending mail using smtp phpmailer doesn't work

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I´m having trouble sending a e-mail with the PHPMailer class, after submit form i have a message mail send ok but i don't recive any mail.

I guess the problem is with the SMTP authentication, but I couldn´t find the problem.the source application are stored in a distant server with ip adress:175.2.3.69 and i use outlook count to send mail

The code with problem is:

```
require_once('../libs/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
//Ensuite on débute l'envoi de mail

$mail = new PHPmailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

try {
    $mail->Host       = "messagerie.abc.a.fr"; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "username.name@a-bc.fr"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password
    $mail->AddReplyTo('username.name@a-bc.fr', 'First Last');
    $mail->AddAddress('username.name@a-bc.fr', 'John Doe');
    $mail->SetFrom('username.name@a-bc.fr', 'First Last');
    $mail->AddReplyTo('username.name@a-bc.fr', 'First Last');
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
    $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
    $mail->Send();

    echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Comment: Have you double checked your spam folder?

Comment: yes but i don't find any mail

Answer (score 1):

PHPMailer will not throw exceptions unless you pass `true` to the constructor, like `$mail = new PHPmailer(true);`, so your code will not cause any exceptions to catch, nor report any errors. I suggest you set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` to get more feedback on the problem.